# Comparing two times in android

Tags: android, time, toast

I have tried with the below code to compare two times:

```
   SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
    Date inTime = sdf.parse("11:00");
    Date outTime = sdf.parse("10:00");

    if(inTime.compareTo(outTime) > 0){
    Toast.makeText(this, "Out time should be greater than In time", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Above code is working fine.

But if I give in time as 11:00 and out time as 12:00, I am getting above toast message.

I am getting above toast message if I give out time from 12:00 to 12:59. In other cases above code is working fine.

Where I am doing wrong. Please help me.

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `java.util.Calendar`, and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now legacy, supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Further adapted for earlier Android in the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change SimpleDateFormat like below...

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
```

Below are the patterns:

```
H   Hour in day (0-23)  Number  0
k   Hour in day (1-24)  Number  24
K   Hour in am/pm (0-11)    Number  0
h   Hour in am/pm (1-12)    Number  12
```

This will work....

Comment: After changing "hh:mm" to "HH:mm", I am getting desired results. Thanks you very much Sanket.

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

Use *java.time*.

```
LocalTime
.parse( "12:00" )
.isAfter(
    LocalTime.parse( "11:00" ) 
)
```

## java.time

You have three problems:

- You are using terrible old date-time classes (`Date` & `SimpleDateFormat`) that were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes.
- Your format of `hh:mm` should have been uppercase for 24-hour clock rather than 12-hour clock: `HH:mm`.
- You are inappropriately trying to represent a time-of-day with a class meant for date-with-time-of-day values.

Use [`LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html). This class represents a time-of-day without a date and without a time zone.

```
LocalTime start = LocalTime.parse( "11:00" ) ;
LocalTime stop = LocalTime.parse( "12:00" ) ;
```

You can compare.

```
boolean isStopAfterStart = stop.isAfter( start ) ;
```

Calculate the elapsed time as a `Duration`.

```
Duration d = Duration.between( start , stop ) ;
```

> d.toString(): PT1H

You can also [ask the `Duration` if it is negative](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#isNegative--), as another way to detect the stop time being before the start.

```
boolean isStopBeforeStart = d.isNegative() ;
```

**Caveat:** Working on time-of-day without the context of a date and a time zone can produce unrealistic results. That approach ignores the anomalies that occur in time zones such as Daylight Saving Time (DST) and other shifts to the wall-clock time used by the people of a particular region. An hour can repeat, or be skipped. A day can be 23, 23.5, 23.75, 25, or other number of hours long.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 0):

```
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TimePicker;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

/**
 * Created by Ketan Ramani on 20/9/18.
 */

public class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {
    private static EditText text;
    private static TextView textTv;
    private static Date startDate = null;
    private static Date fromTime = null;

    public static TimePickerFragment getInstance(View view) {
        if (view instanceof EditText) {
            text = (EditText) view;
        } else if (view instanceof TextView) {
            textTv = (TextView) view;
        }

        return new TimePickerFragment();
    }

    public static TimePickerFragment getInstance(View view, Date fromTimeCalendar) {
        if (view instanceof EditText) {
            text = (EditText) view;
        } else if (view instanceof TextView) {
            textTv = (TextView) view;
        }

        fromTime = fromTimeCalendar;

        return new TimePickerFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        // Create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return it
        return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute, true/*DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity())*/);
    }

    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {

        if (fromTime != null) {

            Calendar fromTimeCal = Calendar.getInstance();
            fromTimeCal.setTime(fromTime);

            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
            Date toDate = null;
            try {
                toDate = sdf.parse(String.format("%02d", hourOfDay) + ":" + String.format("%02d", minute));
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Calendar toTimeCal = Calendar.getInstance();
            toTimeCal.setTime(toDate);

            if (toTimeCal.getTimeInMillis()<fromTimeCal.getTimeInMillis()){
                Helper.showToast(getActivity(),"To time can't less than from time");
            } else {
                if (text != null) {
                    text.setText(getFormatedTime(hourOfDay, minute));
                } else if (textTv != null) {
                    textTv.setText(getFormatedTime(hourOfDay, minute));
                }
            }
        } else {
            if (text != null) {
                text.setText(getFormatedTime(hourOfDay, minute));
            } else if (textTv != null) {
                textTv.setText(getFormatedTime(hourOfDay, minute));
            }
        }
    }

    private String getFormatedTime(int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        int hour, min;
        Calendar datetime = Calendar.getInstance();
        String am_pm = "";
        datetime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
        datetime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);

        if (datetime.get(Calendar.AM_PM) == Calendar.AM)
            am_pm = "AM";
        else if (datetime.get(Calendar.AM_PM) == Calendar.PM)
            am_pm = "PM";
        hourOfDay = hourOfDay > 12 ? hourOfDay - 12 : hourOfDay;
        hour = hourOfDay > 9 ? hourOfDay : hourOfDay;
        min = minute > 9 ? minute : minute;

        return String.format("%02d", hour) + ":" + String.format("%02d", min) + " " + am_pm;
    }

    public void showTimePickerDialog(Context context, View view) {
        DialogFragment newFragment = TimePickerFragment.getInstance(view);
        newFragment.show(((AppCompatActivity) context).getSupportFragmentManager(), "TimePicker");
    }

    public void showTimePickerDialog(Context context, View view, Date fromTime) {
        DialogFragment newFragment = TimePickerFragment.getInstance(view, fromTime);
        newFragment.show(((AppCompatActivity) context).getSupportFragmentManager(), "TimePicker");
    }
}
```

Use

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {

            case R.id.et_from_time:

                TimePickerFragment fromTime = new TimePickerFragment();
                fromTime.showTimePickerDialog(context, v, null);

                mToTimeEt.setText("Select To Time");
                break;

            case R.id.et_to_time:

                if(mFromTimeEt.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Select From Time")){
                    Helper.showToast(context,"Please, select from time first");
                } else {
                    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
                    Date fromDate = null;
                    try {
                        fromDate = sdf.parse(mFromTimeEt.getText().toString());
                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    TimePickerFragment toTime = new TimePickerFragment();
                    toTime.showTimePickerDialog(context, v, fromDate);
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

This class will work for EditText and TextView and set time to respected EditText or TextView if To time is After From Time in HH:mm a Format

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `java.util.Calendar`, and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now legacy, supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Further adapted for earlier Android in the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score -1):

If you are using 24 hour time format then use `kk` instead of `HH`.

```
 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("kk:mm");
```