# SimpleDateFormat return 12 hours ago time between 5.30 to 6.30

Tags: java, postgresql

We are using `SimpleDateFormat` to convert Date Time into time in Milliseconds
bellow is the code we are using for conversion

below is the date-time format I am getting from my database

```
"2019-04-04 12:24:53.754787+00"
```

Code:

```
  SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-M-dd 
  hh:mm:ss");
    Date date = null;
    try {
        date = sdf.parse(dateTime);
    } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    long timeInMilis = date.getTime();
    return timeInMilis;
```

It returns the correct timestamp in milliseconds. Except 5.30 pm to 6.30 pm it return 12 hours delay why it returns wrong timestamp? Or os their any other way to do the conversion?

Comment: You're specifying `hh` for the hour value, and you haven't specified an am/pm specifier. You almost certainly want to use `HH` instead. It's also weird to use `M` with `dd`. It would be far more common to use `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`.

Comment: I suspect Santosh is right about the reason it's specifically between 5:30 and 6:30. (You're currently parsing using the default time zone, which is almost certainly inappropriate.) But the format is another problem. I'd strongly advise you to use `java.time` anyway.

Comment: @JonSkeet while better in general, using java.time has no effect on this specific problem.

Comment: @kumesana: Yes it does - because you'd probably parse to an `Instant`, which implicitly uses UTC, which is *probably* the right thing to do.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated (the former in particular notoriously troublesome). Instead use `OffsetDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: You must parse the offset too (here `+00`), or you will get incorrect results.

Comment: Possible (partial) duplicate of (1) [Difference between java HH:mm and hh:mm on SimpleDateFormat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17341214/difference-between-java-hhmm-and-hhmm-on-simpledateformat), (2) [Comparing two times in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20321711/comparing-two-times-in-android) and/or (3) [12:xx shown as 00:xx in SimpleDateFormat.format(“hh:mm:ss”)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49708445/12xx-shown-as-00xx-in-simpledateformat-formathhmmss)

Comment: Why do you retrieve the timestamp as a string? You should be using `ResultSet.getObject(..., LocalDateTime.class)` to read it from the database. Or at least `ResultSet.getTimestamp()`

Answer (score 3):

First don’t store your datetime as a string in PostgreSQL and don’t retrieve a string like the one you are showing from the database. Store a proper date/time type; in your case probably `timestamp with time zone`. And instead of retrieving a string, fetch a corresponding Java datetime type. For example:

```
    PreparedStatement select = yourDatabaseConnection
            .prepareStatement("select ts from your_table where id = 4;");
    ResultSet rs = select.executeQuery();
    if (rs.next()) {
        OffsetDateTime dateTime = rs.getObject("ts", OffsetDateTime.class);
        long milliseconds = dateTime.toInstant().toEpochMilli();
        // Do something with milliseconds
    }
```

(I have not tested this snippet since I haven’t got PostgreSQL installed.)

If for one reason or another you cannot avoid getting the string:

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSx");
    String stringFromDatabase = "2019-04-04 12:24:53.754787+00";
    OffsetDateTime dateTime
            = OffsetDateTime.parse(stringFromDatabase, formatter);
    long milliseconds = dateTime.toInstant().toEpochMilli();
    System.out.println(milliseconds);
```

This snippet I have tried running. The output is:

> 1554380693754

Since PostgreSQL stores microsecond precision and millisconds since the epoch obviously don’t, we have lost the three last decimals of the original value.

I am using and recommending java.time, the modern Java date and time API. The datetime classes that you tried to use — `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date` — are long outdated and were always poorly designed. So avoid those.

### What went wrong in your code?

- Others have already pointed out that for parsing your string you need uppercase `HH` for hour of day from 00 through 23. Lowercase `hh` is for hour within AM or PM from 01 through 12. Since 12 AM means 00, parsing an hour of 12 gives the wrong result that you have observed, while other hour values work.
- The single `M`, on the other hand, doesn’t matter in this case, it works the same for parsing as `MM` (for formatting we need `MM` if we want two digits always, as in your example string).
- You neither parsed the fraction of second nor the UTC offset of `+00`. If you got an approximately correct result in spite of this, you’ve been struck by luck and should not count on this being the case on other computers or JVMs with other default settings.

### Links

- PostgreSQL [Date/Time Types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/datatype-datetime.html).
- [Using Java 8 Date and Time classes](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/8-date-time.html) from PostgreSQL JDBC driver documentation.
- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- Related question: [Difference between java HH:mm and hh:mm on SimpleDateFormat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17341214/difference-between-java-hhmm-and-hhmm-on-simpledateformat)

Answer (score 0):

As Jon Skeet mentioned, the simple date format is also a bit off. I've changed `-M-` to `-MM-` and `hh` to `HH`. More about SimpleDateFormat can be found on https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html. Also, TimeZone might be affecting it.

You could also use Calendar to return long time.

Example:

```
    String date = "2019-04-04 12:24:53.754787+00";

    private long getTime(String _date) {

        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Vienna"));
        try {
            cal.setTime(format.parse(_date));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // First .getTime() returns Date, second returns long in millis.
        return cal.getTime().getTime(); 
    }
```

Comment: The use of `Calendar` is irrelevant here - the main problem is the format, which you've corrected without mentioning it.

Comment: @Jon Skeet you're totally correct that it's irrelevant, and you're right, I didn't even mention the format.. Thanks